# How to rsync rsnapshots and avoid all the daily.0, daily.1 etc

Tags: backup, rsync, snapshot, nas

I am backuping our servers with rsnapshot on daily bases. 
Everything works fine and I have my data in daily.0, daily.1 ... daily.6

Now, I am using rsync to backup the backups from one to another NAS server.
The problem is that with rsync, on my 2nd backup server (NAS) I have the same data structure with all the daily from 0 to 6.

The big proble is that the NAS is recognizing the data from each daily as sing le physical files, so I have my data multiplied by 7 at the end.

My question is: Is there any possibility to use rsync and have on my 2nd server single files only, without all the daily.0 to daily.6, so I can avoid that the linux system thinks that I have 6 times more data that I have realy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync should only take files that have been modified, so you only have to backup the old data once.

But... (I'm not sure your OS or environment), you can pass only the most recent file to rsync like this

```
latest=`ls -t|head -1` ; rsync $latest backup_location
```

([my source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/rsync-file-by-newest-date-675754/))

Comment: Thank you @psny. This is strange, that is what I read about rsync also (and rsnapshot). But Today I just find out that my NAS server was full (5TB) and my data should not be greater that 3 or 4 TB.

Comment: Do you add the --delete flag to your rsync command? If not, then all old archives will be stored. If the delete flag is there, then you are basically just mirroring the targeted data as a backup.

Comment: Yes, the -delete is there. I just checked on my 1st backup server, The entire snapshod directory has 1000G and each daily individualy is shown between 950G and 970G. I don't know why the NAS server thinks that I have so many data, I will have to check that